Home Button wrongly registers long press on Galaxy S7 (specifically in messenger app)
So this is happening for the last 2 weeks. Whenever I (short) press the home button on my Galaxy S7 (on Android 8.0.0) specifically in the (facebook) messenger app it registers as a long click (opening the google assistant until i disabled it). I'm not sure if it is a messenger problem since Im sure I had this happen in the playstore app as well but cant replicate it right now (so right now its only happening in messenger app). I played around with the Tasker and Automate apps around the time this started happening, but I have also uninstalled them around that time. Might just be a coincidence. I have tried reinstalling the messenger app but that didnt help.
Does anyone have any idea what could cause this or at least give me some pointers on how I might troubleshoot it?
Edit: definitely happens in other apps as well but still mostly in messenger
